# Reverse String order of characters and place into LinkedList using a constructor

Tags: java, string, debugging, linked-list

I am making a program that takes a String and puts it in the opposite order into a LinkedList.

This code doesn't seem to work (wrong input), and I can't figure out why. Any solutions?

```
public LargeInteger(String input) 
{
     TODO
    size=size+input.length();
    LLNode<Integer> curNode=new LLNode<Integer>();
    for(int curPos=input.length()-1;curPos>=0;curPos--)
    {
        if(curPos==input.length()-1)
        {
            head=new LLNode<Integer>();
            head.data=input.charAt(curPos)+'0';
            curNode=head;
        }
        else
        {
            curNode.link=new LLNode<Integer>();
            curNode=curNode.link;
            curNode.data=input.charAt(curPos)+'0';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more details, for example, the implementation of "LLNode". What is the expected output and what do you get? etc

Comment: *I don't get the expected output.* - what is your input? what is your output? what is your expected output? Without this who knows?

Comment: Why are you adding literal `'0'` to your data(s)?

Comment: Elliot, i'm adding 0 to cast my character to an int.

Comment: kayas, LLNode implementation: public class LLNode<T> {
 public T data;
 public LLNode<T> link;
 public LLNode() {
  this(null, null);
 }
 public LLNode(T data, LLNode<T> link) {
  this.data = data;
  this.link = link;
 }
}

Comment: Scary Wombat, there is no output or expected output. It's a constructor. My list stores characters in the string in reverse order.

Comment: If there is no output, then how do you know it isn't working?  You must be checking it somehow...

Comment: There are test classes. This is a school project. I am updating size variable which is probably what it uses to check.

Comment: if by "cast to an int" you mean convert thedigit characters `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'` to their corresponding integer values `1`, `2`, ..., `9`, then you want to **subtract** `'0'`, not add.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Constructor is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

What about to use the methods of List interface and String class, instead of just for loops? Check this example:

```
String phrase = "this is the phrase"; // this is the input
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

// iterates the input in decreasing index order
for(int i=phrase.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    // gets the character from the input and add to the LinkedList
    list.add(Character.toString(phrase.charAt(i))); 
}
```

If you want not to add white spaces, add `if(isEmpty(phrase.charAt(i))) continue;` before adding the character.

Live example [here](http://tpcg.io/5EcrVv).

Comment: I don't have an add method and am not allowed to use one. It's a school project.